# The Server Tag is not well formed - RegularExpressionValidator - parse error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to write a regular expression to check if it contains alphanumeric characters and can include all special characters except single and double quotes. I have used a regular expression validator but it gives a parse error.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPrompt" 
        runat="server"     
        ControlToValidate="txtPrompt"
        Display="Dynamic"
        ErrorMessage="Prompts cannot include single or double quotes, but all other special characters are allowed"
        ForeColor="Red"
        SetFocusOnError="true"
        Text="*"
        ValidationExpression= "^[^'"]+$" />
```

I tried with several validation expression by doubling the "(double quotes. e.g: ValidationExpression= "^[^'""]+$"). But nothing worked. Can someone please tell what is the mistake in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an XML file, and you are trying to include a " in an attribute.  It needs to be replaced with '&quot'.  EG:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPrompt" 
        runat="server"     
        ControlToValidate="txtPrompt"
        Display="Dynamic"
        ErrorMessage="Prompts cannot include single or double quotes, but all other special characters are allowed"
        ForeColor="Red"
        SetFocusOnError="true"
        Text="*"
        ValidationExpression= "^[^'&quot]+$" />
```

Comment: Should that not work if we double the quotes within the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Used a different approach to resolve this issue.
Replace double quotes(") inside the expression with '&quot';